# Proper grammar with ellipsis?

Tags: grammaticality, past-participles, ellipses, simple-past

Bear with me, please. Consider this sentence:

> "He might've turned his head and **seen** the incident, but I'm not sure."

This sounds awkward, but it makes sense, as *seen* agrees with *might have*. But this look at this sentence:

> "He might've turned his head and **saw** the incident..."

This sounds more natural, and I would prefer to use this.

My question is as follows: When omitting words that are implied (in this case, *he might have*), does grammar follow the ellipsis or what is actually there? Since the *he might have* is omitted before *seen*, should one just use the simple past *saw* or the past participle *seen*? I'm not explaining this as well as I could, but that's the best I can do. If anyone understands what I'm asking, please feel free to edit this question accordingly.

Comment: In this case, I think the ellipsis would pull in the whole thing "*He might've* (...) and (*he might've*) seen …".

Comment: @Lawrence What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's not just "He might (have turned …) and (he might) *see* …", with the ellipsis pulling in just the "he might" part, and neither is it "He (might've …) and saw …", where there's arguably no ellipsis at all.

Comment: The issue is not whether grammar is controlling the verbs, but whether the grammar is maintaining the natural progression of time. The moment we use the present perfect it fills up the time from the action (turn head) to the present - which leaves no time in which to insert a past action (saw).

Comment: I think I understand now what your question asks. If so, the answer is that ellipsis preserves the grammar, as if the omitted words weren't omitted.

Comment: So, it is parsed like this? "He might have turned his head and [he might have] seen the incident." The ellipsis is thus treated as though it were actually there, correct?

Comment: You've got it .

Comment: @Lawrence Great. If you could post this as a detailed answer, I'd be grateful. Also, I'm curious why that is. Why isn't the ellipsis treated as though it weren't there, like in "He might have turned his head and saw the incident"?

Comment: Because English verb grammar describes a time-relation environment. As I said, the present perfect is designed to fill the time between the trigger action and the present moment. There is no time left for a simple action, only parallel or nearly parallel perfect actions, utilising the same time space. This is why we cannot use all time phrases with all tenses: the tense and the time phrase should describe the same time period.

Comment: @TrevorChristopherButcher Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: He might have [turned his head] and [seen the incident], but I'm not sure." The two bracketed elements are a coordination of two non-finite clause serving as complement of "have". "Might have turned ... / "might have seen ..." are perfect constructions requiring a past participle, and  hence "seen" is a past participle, just as "turned" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One trait that many types and instances of ellipsis have in common is that the appearance of ellipsis is optional. The occurrence of VP-ellipsis, for instance, is often optional, e.g. He will help, and she will (help), too. Whether or not the second occurrence of the verb help is elided in this sentence is up to the speaker and to communicative aspects of the situational context in which the sentence is uttered. This optionality is a clear indication of ellipsis.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))

Although the article continues on to describe exceptions, the above makes for a good rule of thumb: a sentence that is considered to contain ellipsis (of the standard sort) must communicate identically whether with or without the ellipsis.

As such, **the grammar of both forms follows that of the full (no ellipsis) form**.

If you consider "He might've turned his head and seen the incident" to contain ellipsis, it would be natural to consider the full form to be:

- He might've turned his head and  <sub>he might've</sub>  seen the incident.

Grammatically, you can't substitute *saw* for *seen* in that sentence, so *saw* doesn't work in the ellipsed version, either.

Now, you could argue that the conjunction has two elements:

- He might've turned his head.
- He saw the incident.

In this case, you'd argue that only the word "he" was elided: "He might've turned his head and  <sub>he</sub>  saw the incident".

However, this feels unnatural. I suspect it has something to do with the uncertainty of "might have turned" contradicting the certainty of "he saw", where the seeing appears to be contingent on the turning. Alternatively, we might consider the modal verb *might* to be so dominant that it naturally attaches to both parts of the conjunction, so *saw* doesn't work because * *might saw* doesn't work, grammatically.

Either way, if we provide the second part with an explicit [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality), the sentence works again:

- He might've turned his head and  <sub>he</sub>  *definitely* saw the incident.